# Multiplicative inverse of a gaussian integer

Tags: inverse, gaussian-integers

So, I had to prove that Gaussian integers had an identity element and ended up with it being $(1 + 0i)$. Now I have to see if any $(a+bi)$ (except $(0 + 0i)$)has a multiplicative inverse. Then I ended up with this:
\begin{align*}
 ac-bd &= 1\\
 ad + bc &= 0\\
\end{align*}
But I don't really know if I can prove that for any given $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ I can find $c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that that happens.
Am I on the wrong path?
Can I really prove it?

Comment: It's $ad+bc=0$, not $ad+bd$.

Comment: You have a typo ($d$ in both terms of the second equation.) Look up the norm of a Gaussian integer.  It streamlines questions about multiplicative topics in the Gaussian integers enormously, just as the multiplicative determinant function is helpful for issues about invertibility of matrices.

Comment: $\pm1$ and $\pm i$ have inverses

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @KCd Got it, I'll look it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

1. Consider the application $N : a+ib \mapsto a^2+b^2$
2. Show that for every $a+ib$ and $c+id$, one has $N((a+ib)(c+id))=N(a+ib)N(c+id)$.
3. Deduce that if $a+ib$ has a multiplicative inverse, then $N(a+ib)=\pm 1$.
4. Deduce all the Gaussian integers which have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: So, not all the gaussian integers have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Try to follow the given steps, you will be able to figure this out by yourself. @RaulPeña

Comment: OK, so I got that, since $N$ is multiplicative, then $N((a+bi)(a+bi)') = N(1) = 1$. Then, I have that, since $(a+bi)$ and $(a+bi)'$ should be gaussian integers, we have that they must both be $\pm 1$. Then, since $N(a+bi) = a^{2} + b^{2}$ the only gaussian integer that satisfies this is $(1+0i)$. Did I do this right?

Comment: @RaulPeña You are close. Indeed, if $a+ib$ has an inverse, you must have $N(a+ib)=\pm 1$. So you get $a^2+b^2 = \pm 1$. Now try to solve that. ($1+0i$ is not the only solution).

Comment: My bad. Another solution is $(0+1i)$, since $0^{2} + i^{2} = 0 - 1 = -1$, right?

Comment: @RaulPeña Hum, be careful ! The equation is $a^2+b^2=\pm 1$, not $a^2 + (ib)^2 = \pm 1$... (and $a$ and $b$ are integers here !!)

Comment: My bad, once again. But $(0+1i)$ is still the other solution, right? $0^{2} + 1^{2} = 1$. And since it's $a^{2} + b^{2}$ and not $a^{2} + (bi)^{2}$, then there's no solution that gives us $-1$, right?

Comment: @RaulPeña Indeed, there is no solution with $-1$, and $(0+1i)$ is also a solution. But there are again other solutions :) If $a^2+b^2=1$, and $a$ and $b$ are integers, what are the different possibilities for $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: $N$ must be non-negative

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ohhh, $(\pm 1 + 0i)$ and $(0 \pm 1i)$.

Comment: @RaulPeña You got it. So you have only four potential solutions, that are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$. To be complete, you finally just have to check that these solutions *really* have an inverse (what you proved is that they have $N(.)=1$, but this is just - a priori - a necessary condition)

Comment: ,@TheSilverDoe Thanks a lot. I think I can go on my own from here.

Comment: @RaulPeña You are welcome !